# PHP Curl and JSON confusion

Tags: php, api, curl, json

I'm trying to understand how getting an access_token works with CURL.

```
$url = "https://api.com/oauth/access_token";
$access_token_parameters = array(
    'client_id'     =>     '',
    'client_secret'     =>     '',
    'grant_type'        =>     '',
    'redirect_uri'      =>     '',
    'code'          =>     $_GET['code']
);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I'm supposed to get a JSON string with this right?

I tried a various of things to output the string

```
$test = json_decode($result);
print_r($test); 

$arr = json_encode($result,true);
foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val['access_token'];  
}
```

Am I doing this wrong?

I believe the correct JSON output should be something like this :

```
{
    "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
    "user": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg"
    }
}
```

But this is not working? I'm trying to get the access_token from the server.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: What happens when you try your examples? What kind of errors are you getting? Also, instead of `print_r` or iterating over the results. Just try `var_dump`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use below function to get content

```
 $response = get_web_page($url);
 $resArr = array();
 $resArr = json_decode($response);
//echo"<pre>"; print_r($resArr); echo"</pre>";
    function get_web_page($url) {
          $options = array (CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false, // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", // handle compressed
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "test", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true, // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120, // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10 ); // stop after 10 redirects
          $ch = curl_init ( $url );
          curl_setopt_array ( $ch, $options );
          $content = curl_exec ( $ch );
          $err = curl_errno ( $ch );
          $errmsg = curl_error ( $ch );
          $header = curl_getinfo ( $ch );
          $httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );
          curl_close ( $ch );
          $header ['errno'] = $err;
          $header ['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
          $header ['content'] = $content;
          return $header ['content'];
         }
```